# Stored procedure incrementar crédito

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Sou iniciante em MYSQL e peguei uns exercícios de uma apostila para praticar, mas tô meio perdido agora

Tenho que fazer o seguinte:

-credit_game nome da tabela a ser atualizada

-value e user são os campos da tabela

-param_value valor a ser creditado

-param_cod_user identificação dos jogadores dentro do jogo

Fora as informações acima não tem mais nada para fazer o stored procedure

Tentei algo parecido com o que fiz abaixo em um exercício anterior, mas dessa vez não funciona, acho que porque não tenho muita certeza do que fazer com o param_value e o param_cod_user

```
BEGIN
UPDATE credit_game
SELECT value, user
END
```

Comment: *"incrementar crédito"* faça `update TABELA set campo=campo+1` isso vai incrementar, e no lugar do 1 pode ser qualquer valor de incremento que deseje

Comment: Certo, obrigado vou testar aqui para ver se funciona